# Remote commands, same user, different behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Very surprised by the following behaviour:-

Two remote machines, `remoteA` and `remoteB`.

When I ssh in and execute these commands on the remote hosts:

```
john@remoteA:~$ which python
 /home/john/anaconda3/bin/python

john@remoteB:~$ which python
 /home/john/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Same version of python.

However, when I run the commands remotely in a single line without initiating an ssh session as follows:

```
john@my_computer:~$ ssh john@remoteA which python
 /usr/bin/python

john@my_computer:~$ ssh john@remoteB which python
```

(no output in the second case, indeed remote python commands to `remoteB` result in a 'command not found' error.)

I am confused because the user is the same, so shouldn't the path be the same?
Fwiw, on both remote machines the path is set in the .profile file:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/564926/450332